how to call a function on closing a tab in primeng tab component, p-tabPanel, p-tabView in Angular
<p-tabView [controlClose]="true">
    <p-tabPanel *ngFor="let tab of tabs"
                [header]="tab.actionName"
                (click)="selectTab(tab)"
                [selected]="tab.selected"
                (onClose) = "close(tab)"
                [closable]="tab.closable">
    </p-tabPanel>
  </p-tabView>
  
  <ng-container *ngIf="selectedTab">
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="selectedTab.actionComponent; inputs: selectedTab.inputs"></ng-container>
  </ng-container>


i want to call a funtion to perform some action whenever i close some tab, unfortunately the onclose is not working on p-tabPanel
I recently faced the same issue, the problem is the (onClose) does not work on p-tabPanel, it works on p-tabView only so we need to use the (onClose) on p-tabView only and pass an Event the event gives the index of tab to be removed and then we can remove the tab in our .ts code, i am providing code snippet below for better understanding
<p-tabView (onClose)="onTabClose($event)" [controlClose]="true">
  <p-tabPanel *ngFor="let tab of tabs; let i = index"
              [header]="tab.title"
              [closable]="true">
    <!-- Tab Content -->
    <ng-container *ngIf="selectedTab === tab">
      <!-- Display content for the selected tab -->
    </ng-container>
  </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>`

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TabViewCloseEvent } from 'primeng/tabview';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab-example',
  templateUrl: './tab-example.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tab-example.component.css']
})
export class TabExampleComponent implements OnInit {
  tabs = [
    { title: 'Tab 1', content: 'Content 1' },
    { title: 'Tab 2', content: 'Content 2' },
    { title: 'Tab 3', content: 'Content 3' }
  ];
  selectedTab = this.tabs[0]; // Initially select the first tab

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  onTabClose(event: TabViewCloseEvent) {
    const index = event.index; // Get the index of the tab to close
    this.tabs.splice(index, 1); // Remove the tab from the list

    // Select a new tab if the closed tab was the selected one
    if (this.selectedTab === this.tabs[index]) {
      this.selectedTab = this.tabs.length ? this.tabs[0] : null; // Select a new tab or clear selection
    }
  }
}

In PrimeNG, when you click the close icon on a tab (using p-tabPanel inside p-tabView), the following happens:
The onClose event is triggered.
The event provides information about which tab was clicked.
You handle the event by removing the tab from the list of tabs.
The p-tabView component updates the UI to reflect the removal of the tab.
This process allows users to dynamically close tabs, and the p-tabView component ensures the view remains consistent with the updated list of tabs.
Hope, this helps!!
